# What is the best way to calculate values over time from incoming stream

Tags: c#, performance, collections

Running a C# .net app that receives data every 30 seconds from 100 clients and then stores data in a database. The data is for two parameters for each client. I need to determine the total for each parameter, for each client per hour and make decisions based on the results. The decisions algorithm would be making decisions for the last hour worth of data in a sliding window fashion. My initial thinking is to keep a dictionary of those 100 clients with key being client IP, and value being a running total. However 1) if my app restarts half way through the hour or at minute 59, I lose all those warm running totals. 2) if more clients start sending data, dictionary will consume more memory, 3) if in the future the 2 parameters become 100, the dictionary grows even bigger 4) making the running total value always reflect one-hour worth of recent data is not straightforward.

Is there any different approaches I should consider? best-practice? design patterns?

Comment: This is extremely broad, but here are my two cents: 1-store the data on database, 2-*key being client IP* very bad idea, two different clients can have the same external ip (traffic through a proxy, nat, anything else). For 2, on the client side generate a GUID and store it on the client, then when the client connects send that id, in this way you will identfy unequivocally each client, even you can have multiple clients on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks. IP is a bad idea I agree. I'll use a GUID. For database storage, I will be storing the incoming data as it arrives. The decision making logic runs on the data before storage. Or did you mean, store it, then have the decision logic periodically work out of the database? I was trying to avoid that since it may not perform well with db reads and constant writes.

Comment: yes, I meant to run it on intervals over the stored data. ANd about performance, you say you will have 100 clients, how many registers do you expect to create per client second? any actual db will work fast enough to support thousands of writes per second, so depending on the volume of transactions it may be fast enough or not.

Comment: "Is there any different approaches I should consider?" - yes, consider using a messaging broker, for example RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

Very broad, but I will try to define structure:

1. Identify each client with sequential 8-byte integer, UID. Not GUID, not even sequential GUID. 4-byte integer is an option but I would stick with 8-byte. Seed from 100,000.
2. Identify each call from user with sequential 8-byte integer, CID. Not GUID, not even sequential GUID. 4-byte integer is an option but I would stick with 8-byte. I would take number of microseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00 as CID.
3. Store all data in archive database table REPORT_ARCHIVE, UID+CID being the complex PK. Cluster table on CID hash, make it chunky (1 file per year/quater of recordings).
4. Store last N records (N depends on your time window, should be your config value) in operational database table REPORT_OPER, UID+CID being the complex PK. Cluster on UID hash (8-16 files).
5. Pipeline all you incoming calls in memory structure like queue. Async processing agents should grab records out of queue. Grab by chunks, save into DB using DB chunking (SQL server and Oracle support that). Save to REPORT_OPER table, set trigger on INSERT to push data from REPORT_OPER to REPORT_ARCHIVE.
6. Run all your work queries against REPORT_OPER (summing up, etc), your analytics may run over REPORT_ARCHIVE.
7. For something like SUM of last X reports I would cache SUM in memory in ConcurrentDictionary using UID as key. IMPORTANT: cache on request call (admin asks for totals), not on insert call (user calls in on 30 sec interval). For that you need to agree on SLA - what is the accepted latency on reporting totals. If client wants near-real-time - negotiate frequency of calls to calculate cache hit/miss.

Good luck.